# Звук WebRTC Android

Tags: android, webrtc

Делаю проект с видеозвонками на WebRTC. Все работает отлично, но звук идет через телефон, а не через динамик. Копался в AudioManager - не нашел ничего подходящего. Как перевести звук с телефона на динамик?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось очень просто. Забыл слово Speakerphone.

```kotlin
audioManager.isSpeakerphone = true
```